# Installing Android-x86 on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, android-x86

Can you install [Android-x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android-x86) on the same partition as the Windows?

Comment: On the same partition, if you did that, you would replace Windows with Android

Comment: Thanks for the information [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Using remixOS, you can install it onto the same partition and dual boot remixOS and Windows. RemixOS is like android for pc.

Comment: mac too, of course.

Comment: I mean, it works on Mac OS X too.

Comment: Just google RemixOS to find it.

Comment: Thanks for the information [Aiden Hong](https://superuser.com/users/699984/aiden-hong).

Comment: The instructions will be in the zip file you download. Remember, don't install it on an external space!